# SOAP UI - significance of representation in REST projects

Tags: rest, soapui

In Soap UI REST project, what is the significance or use of adding representations under a method(say POST). I see three types of representations - REQUEST, RESPONSE and FAULT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that it's only informative, it shows the different kind of interactions you send/received from the REST service.

You can add new ones manually but I think that this has nonsense because when you invoke the service if your receive a correct response a new entry of kind `RESPONSE` is added automatically specifying the media-type, http status code and name received from the service.

If instead you receive an error http status like 404, then a new entry of kind `FAULT` is added specifying also the media-type, http status and name for the fault.

The `REQUEST` type entry it's only added when you send a REST Request of POST type , if the REST Request is a GET then the entry is not added.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks. I think it explains a lot!

Comment: The strange thing is that all Fault which did ever occur for this rest call are also saved in the project.xml file ???